# USB Memory Stick hidden partition

Tags: c#, .net, usb-drive, disk-partitioning

I am writing a kind of accounting software which will run portable on a USB Memory Stick. I would like to make a hidden partition on the Stick to store some data to check the validity of the database file on the main partition. Currently I don't know how to start. Could anyone tell me any way to do it? What partition type should I use? How do I read from it with C# .NET? What Win32 APIs are there. Anything.

UPDATE:
Here's a scenario, I use a file (encrypted) to store a value (e.g. Amount of money), the user can backup that file, and whenever he restore the file, he restore the value at the time he backup. That's why I want to have a hidden partition. Encryption is not an option for me.

Comment: What about embedding the data in NTFS alternate streams? http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ntfsstreams.aspx

Comment: is there anyway to copy protect NTFS-ADS?

Comment: I suppose you don't want your user to be able to modify the backup files right? Shouldn't adding some integrity check with digital signatures do the trick?

Comment: @Martheen: That doesn't protect against a replay attack.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than hiding you can use encryption

[How to lock a folder on a USB drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541155/how-to-lock-a-folder-on-a-usb-drive)

Answer (score 1):

There is a [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) project that does something similar you want. It is open source, so you might take a look how they are doing that.